# Problems on Compact Framework when communication is lost

Tags: c#, sockets, compact-framework, backgroundworker

I have a problem on a hand held device that should be listening for messages from my server application.  When the device loses connection to the network my server is on, this background worker (implemented from OpenNetCF) stops responding.  I've placed messages in the ProgressChanged and RunWorkerCompleted events to see when they are raised, and in the following code after the RecieveFrom in the while loop, and after the loop termination, as well as in all of the exceptions.  I don't see the messages from the exceptions, or after the while loop at all, and the messages stop after the connection is lost.  All of the messages are shown by setting the text in a visible label, with the background colour of the label changing so that I can see if the loop is running.  The loop seems to stop running, even after the connection is re-gained, and attempting to re-run the backgroundworker generates an "Already in use" exception.  So, why would the worker stop responding while continuing to run?

```
  private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
  {
      BackgroundWorker wWorker = (BackgroundWorker)sender;
      byte[] wBytes = new Byte[4096];
      string wsReceive;
      EndPoint wRemoteEP = (EndPoint)new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);

      try
      {
          while (true)
          {
              if (wWorker.CancellationPending)
              {
                  break;
              }

              mSocket.ReceiveFrom(wBytes, ref wRemoteEP);
              if (wBytes.Length < 1)
              {
                  continue;
              }
              wsReceive = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(wBytes, 0, wBytes.Length);

              wWorker.ReportProgress(0, wsReceive);
          }
          mSocket.Close();
      }
      catch (ThreadAbortException)
      {
      }
      catch (ThreadStateException)
      {
      }
      catch (Exception E)
      {
          MessageBox.Show(E.Message, "Communication Error");
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right from [the docs on `Socket.ReceiveFrom`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdfskwcy%28v=VS.90%29.aspx):

> If no data is available for reading, the ReceiveFrom method will block until data is available

So when communication is lost, you're unable to receive and your ReceiveFrom call blocks indefinitely.  It's going to stop reporting anything while it waits for data, but the thread is still alive and therefore the BackgroundWorker can't be re-run.

Comment: Does this mean that when connection is regained, and data is sent by the server, the client side ReceiveFrom would then listen again?  It doesn't seem to, would the socket still be valid?

Comment: Just a quick followup, putting an If check for the socket.Available seems to avoid the hanging problem on the ReceiveFrom, and now the loop stops, the background worker stops and I can re-start it in the RunWorkerCompleted.  I now have an OutOfMemory exception being thrown I have to chase down.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Just my 2 cents:

Whenever I implement a socket communication, I treat 0 bytes received as an indication that the remote server has closed gracefully. I think that you should also treat this to start a reconnection attempt, instead of just "continuing" the loop.

Comment: If you don't mind my asking, how would you do a re-connection in this situation?